# Click or Select feature layer based on attributes

Tags: django, postgresql, openlayers

I am using Openlayers API, I have added a layer from my PostgreSQL database using Django framework (GeoDjango).

I have a problem on how to search a specific feature based on its attributes.

Here's my code:

```
$("#landpin").change(function () {
    for (var f = 0; f < mylayer.features.length; f++) {
        if (mylayer.features[f].attributes.clandpin == this.value) {
            $("#clickfeature").click(function () {
                featsel = mylayer.features[f];
                selectControl.clickFeature(featsel);
            });
            break;
        }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **getFeaturesByAttribute** method:

```
features = mylayer.getFeaturesByAttribute(attr_name, attr_value);
```

Comment: How do I trigger that in a click event?

Comment: you said "I have a problem on how to search a specific feature based on its attributes". and this line give features to you? please give more explain about click event.

Comment: Yah, notice my code in the question. I want to select the feature based on attributes by clicking the button id `clickfeature`.

Comment: you can call .select(features) on your [Select Control](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getFeaturesByAttribute method, for example:

```
for(var f=0;f<layer.features.length;f++) {
  if(layer.features[f].attributes.someAttribute == 'desiredValue') {
    selectFeatureControl.select(layer.features[f]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Reference : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63966/openlayers-select-a-feature-from-attribute-or-id